# Update Shiny DT & SQLite after values changed in editable renderDT object

Tags: r, sqlite, shiny, shinydashboard, dt

I have created a [Shiny app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3BKfS.png) for an editable SQLite membership database dashboard. My plan is to use the DT and DBI packages to edit specific values, then push the updates back to the SQLite table by dropping the old one and writing the new one in its place (haven't coded the drop table yet, but will go into button actions).

The UI side behaves as expected, but when I edit a page and hit my Write to Table button, then reload or close out of the app, it does not look like the DT or database has updated.

My questions (beyond "How can this work?"):

1. When the editable function works right, is it editing long_sepal or data?
2. Should I be able to see the updates in the Global environment as they are made?

I included a reprex using Iris.db as a dataset below.

Thank you! -Justin

```html
library(shiny)
require(shinydashboard)
library(dplyr)
library(RSQLite)
library(DBI)
library(dbplyr)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)

#create SQLite connection and open it
con <- DBI::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), 
                      "/Users/admin/ICG/iris.db")

src_dbi(con)

#split SQLite datatable into two seperate datatables
data <- tbl(con, "data")
data <- data %>% as.data.frame()
long_sepal <- filter(data, sepal_length>5.5)
short_sepal <- filter(data, sepal_length<5.5)

header <- dashboardHeader(title="Iris Dashboard")

#sidebar with "Write to DB" reactive button
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(sidebarMenu(
  div(style="display:inline-block;width:32%;text-align: 
      center;",actionButton("action", label = "Write to 
                            DB"))))

#Body element of the dashboard
frow1 <- fluidRow(
  
  box(
    title = "Long Sepal"
    ,status = "primary"
    ,solidHeader = TRUE 
    ,collapsible = TRUE 
    ,DTOutput("table1", height = "300px")
  )
  
  ,box(
    title = "Short Sepal"
    ,status = "primary"
    ,solidHeader = TRUE 
    ,collapsible = TRUE 
    ,DT::dataTableOutput(outputId = "table2", height = 
                           "300px")
  )    
)
# merge into dashBoard body
body <- dashboardBody(frow1)

# Define UI for dashboard page and 
ui <- dashboardPage(title = 'Iris Dashboard', 
                     header, sidebar,
                    body, skin = 'black'
)

# Define server logic required for editable tables
server <- function(input, output) {  
  
  output$table1 <- renderDT(long_sepal, options = 
                              list(scrollX = TRUE), editable = TRUE)
  output$table2 <- renderDT(short_sepal, options = 
                              list(scrollX = TRUE), editable = TRUE)
  
  #necessary code to replace data once edited
  proxy1 = dataTableProxy('table1')
  
  observeEvent(input$x2_cell_edit, {
    info = input$x2_cell_edit
    str(info)
    i = info$row
    j = info$col
    v = info$value
    long_sepal[i, j] <<- DT::coerceValue(v, 
                                            long_sepal[i, j])
    replaceData(proxy1, long_sepal, resetPaging = 
                  TRUE)  # important
  })
  
  #Write to SQLite database
  data <- eventReactive(input$action, {
    dbWriteTable(con, "data", data.frame(data), append 
                 = TRUE)
    data <- dbReadTable(con, "data")
    return(data)
  })  
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```